# LINQ to filter duplicate column values and replace duplicate values column

Tags: vb.net

I have this table:

```
Code   ------     Version   
AAA    ------      0.0.0.0    
AAA     ------     0.0.0.1    
AAA     ------     0.0.0.1   
AAA     ------     0.0.0.1   
AAA     ------     0.0.0.1   
BBB    ------      0.0.0.0    
CCC     ------     0.0.0.0    
CCC     ------     0.0.0.0
```

This is my data in a table, and I want to convert this into:

```
Code    ------     Version   
AAA    ------      0.0.0.0    
AAA    ------      0.0.0.1    
AAA    ------      0.0.0.2   
AAA    ------      0.0.0.3   
AAA    ------      0.0.0.4  
BBB    ------      0.0.0.0    
CCC   ------       0.0.0.0    
CCC   ------       0.0.0.1
```

Nowadays, I'm trying to do some test with looks, however, I consider it might be improved with LINQ. This is my current code:

```
For Each row As DataRow In duplicateEntityRecords.Rows
    Dim strkey = row(0).ToString
    foundrows = dataObject.Tables("tables").Select("version= '" & strkey & "'")
    If foundrows.Length > 1 AndAlso Not strkey.Equals(String.Empty) Then 
        Dim increment As String = "1"
        For i As Integer = 1 To
            foundrows.GetUpperBound(0)
            foundrows(i)("friendlyname") = foundrows(i)("friendlyname") + increment increment = increment + 1
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Is this possible to perform the same task with LINQ?

Comment: Can you provide us what have you done?

Comment: For Each row As DataRow In duplicateEntityRecords.Rows
            Dim strkey = row(0).ToString
            foundrows = dataObject.Tables("tables").Select("version= '" & strkey & "'")
            If foundrows.Length > 1 AndAlso Not strkey.Equals(String.Empty) Then
                Dim increment As String = "1"
                For i As Integer = 1 To foundrows.GetUpperBound(0)
                    foundrows(i)("friendlyname") = foundrows(i)("friendlyname") + increment
                    increment = increment + 1
                Next
            End If
        Next

Comment: But i am not much familiar with LINQ so i am looping which is performance concern..so Need to Use LINQ @FedericoNavarrete

Answer (score 0):

You can group by an anonymous type and then use `First` to get only one per group:

```
Dim query = From row In table
            Group row By row.Code, row.Version Into codeVersionGroup = Group
            Select codeVersionGroup.First()

For Each x In query
    Console.WriteLine("{0}---{1}",x.Code, x.Version)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i want all the fields in that Table. i didnt want to take first

Comment: @Nani: it takes all fields, it just returns only one record per group, so removes duplicates

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think the OP doesnt want duplicates removing, but wants to have replace non-unique versions with unique ones for each code.

Comment: @DavidWilson but that is done by this query. It will only survive one row per group